# Using Function from Model

Tags: php, yii

Users.php (model):

```
...
public function hashPassword($password){
    $hashed = hash('sha256', $password . self::HASH_CODE);
    return $hashed;
}
...
```

UserIdentity.php

```
...
else if($user->password!==Users::hashPassword($this->password))
...
```

Error:

```
Non-static method Users::hashPassword() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define `hashPassword()` as a static function in order to call it with `Users::hashPassword()`:

```
public static function hashPassword($password) {
    ...
```

Otherwise, you can create an instance of the `Users` class and call it in a non-static manner:

```
$users = new Users();
$users->hashPassword($password);
```

In a strictly-`yii` sense, you may be able to call it with the following (depending on your setup):

```
Yii::app()->Users->hashPassword($password);
```

Comment: Making it static is the best way?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento Due to the purpose of the method, yeah - it looks like it is a great candidate for being static.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if($user->password!==Users::model()->hashPassword($this->password))
```

this is not a static method

Answer (score 1):

Make function `static`

```
public static function hashPassword($password){
    $hashed = hash('sha256', $password . self::HASH_CODE);
    return $hashed; }
```